# MySQL: storing related BOOL preferences all in one integer as each bit of it's binary value

Tags: mysql, algorithm

Would it be beneficial for my performance/storage space to save related preferences (all booleans) in an integer as if each preference is one bit of the correspondent binary value of that preference? If so, significantly?

I have a bunch of user preferences of boolean type on my website that are related to each other, so I thought it might be beneficial to group them all into one int, as if each preference was a bit of the number, like so:

if I have 5 preferences, each one would have a power of 2 worth from 2^0 til 2^4. If the preference is true I add that value to the int column on the database and if it's not I don't add anything

first preference value: 1
second preference value: 2
third preference value: 4
fourth preference value: 8
fifth preference value: 16

if only first, third and fourth preferences are activated, my total sum would be 13  (1+4+8), and I could check if each one is there by checking

(total_sum % 2^(i)) >= 2^(i-1)

where i is for the i-th preference.

for the example:

13 % 2^(1) >= 2^(1-1)  -> 13%2 >= 1 -> True, so 1st preference is on

13 % 2^(2) >= 2^(2-1)  -> 13%4 >= 2 -> False, so 2nd preference is off

and so on...

Comment: As far as storage is concerned - there will obviously be a saving - whether it is worthwhile would be dependant on the number of users. Similarly with performance, there will be a very small improvement (but maybe not noticeable) but you have the added complexity of packing & unpacking the data which may have implications if you changed the user preferences in the future. Check out the BIT datatype as an alternative to INT : https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/bit-type.html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The questions I would ask are:

1. Is disk cost an issue for you? Mostly no. So keep multiple columns.
2. Are you frequently running queries on the preference from various places? Then do not use complex logic and keep it complex. Also anyone reading the column should know the mapping to bit position.
3. If you have a big team, over time people will mess these bit positions

Keep things simple. Do not complicate unless its unavoidable.